# id constantly being clicked using setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating an audio web player which I would like to function continuously, meaning that when a piece of audio finishes playing, it moves onto playing the next one.

However, I have come across a problem where everything works as it should, but once the previous audio finishes playing, and the next one starts, every 2 seconds, the new one will play & pause; **continuously**.

This is my current `JavaScript` code block:

```
function playPauseButton(button, wave, trackID){
    var button = $(button); // play button

    if(wave.isPlaying()){ // if the audio is playing and the user clicks play button, pause the audio
        button.removeClass("playing");
        wave.pause();
    } else { // vice versa
        button.addClass("playing");
        wave.play();
    }
    waveDuration = wave.getDuration(); // audio duration
    var nextTrack = ++trackID; // get the current audio track ID and plus 1 to get the new track ID

    setInterval(function(){ // check every 2 seconds if the audio is finished playing
        if(wave.getCurrentTime() >= waveDuration){ // if it has, make the play button a pause button
            button.removeClass("playing");
            $(nextTrack + '-ppbutton').click(); // simulate new track play button click
        }    
    }, 2000);
}
```

& my very simple `HTML` play button:

```
<!-- onclick play audio (if paused), pause audio (if playing) !-->
<div onclick="playPauseButton(this, a2wave, 2);" id="2-ppbutton"></div>
<!-- 2 is the id !-->
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, however, it is still confusing me (I'm not that good at JavaScript)

All help & suggestions are appreciated.

I've tried to comment on everything to help you understand

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to Vlaz for fixing my issue; really appreciate it! :)

However, if people would still like to make suggestions or edits, you are more than welcome too!

Thanks.

Comment: `setInterval` performs an action _at an interval_ until cancelled. Were you looking for `setTimeout` or perhaps `clearInterval`?

Comment: @vlaz yes I'm aware of that, however, it is supposed to check whether the audio has ended or not, consistently. and I assume using `clearInterval` or using `setTimeout` would break this?

Am I wrong? Is there a way to implement it? :)

Comment: OK, looking at it more closely, you probably intended to `setInterval` however, I believe your usage is wrong. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: quick comment: is it normal that your function expects 4 arguments, and only 3 are passed via the HTML `onclick` ?

Comment: @vlaz oh damn. ok, thankyou :)

Comment: @ValLeNain haha, that's a typo. intended to get rid of that while editing the code block for easier eye use, and to get rid of code that isn't relevant :) sorry about that

Comment: shouldn't you update the `wave` variable to point to new audio file?

Comment: Why are you continuously checking the audio is still playing, when you could more easily just listen for the [`ended` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended) on the `<audio>` (or `<video>`) element?

Comment: @DavidThomas there are no `<audio>` or `<video>` elements.

Comment: MDN disagrees with you: [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio), [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video). Now, whether you're *using* those elements is another matter (if not, why not? They make it a lot easier to manage audio/video) of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

Your usage of `setInterval` will launch a new ticker *every* time the button is pressed. So after three presses, you'd have three of them running. Also, remember that each will be running their own checks, as well. So I believe I know where your problem is, here is an overview

1. `setInterval` is called the first time, let's call it **intervalPrime**. Let's assume the duration of the song is 60 seconds.
2. The song continues with a check every 2 seconds, eventually ends.
3. A new `setInterval` is called when the play button is clicked - this creates a new interval - let's call it **intervalSecond**. This one will be checking for a new song and new duration, however the details are irrelevant.
4. The song plays and **intervalSecond** monitors if it's finished yet.
5. At the same time **intervalPrime** is still doing it's check. And since `wave.getCurrentTime()` likely returns `60` (end of the song), then the check it does is `60 >= 60` which passes, so it clicks the button.

## How to avoid it

### Remove old intervals

What you could do is ensure you only have one `setInterval` active at a time. The function returns an ID of the timer, so you could do something akin to this

```
var currentChecker;

function playPause() {
   /* .... */
   if (shouldClick) {
     clearTimeout(currentChecker);
     currentChecker = setInterval( /* ... */ );
   }
}
```

(illustrative)

So, essentially try to maintain a single one by stopping the previous interval before starting a new one.

### Keep only one interval

An alternative is to only have one interval active and maintain a state, so you can have something like

```
var masterLoop = setInterval(function() {
    var wave = getCurrentWave(); //fetching it will depend on your application

     if(wave.getCurrentTime() >= wave.getDuration()){
          /* handle what happens */
     }
} , 2000);
```

### Use `setInterval` when the song finishes.

I'm not familiar with the API you use for playing the sounds, but if it's possible to hook onto the end event, you might be able to use simple `setTimeout` when that occurs, like so

```
  //assuming the API allows to do something like this
  wave.onFinish(function() {
      setInterval(playNext, 2000);
  })
```

### More than one of these

If the API does not provide a way to hook onto the finished playing event, a better alternative is to combine the last two. Have a master loop that checks the state of the track and when finished, uses `setInterval` to schedule the next song. The interval delay will probably need to be set lower, but it will lead to a more consistent time between tracks, since a song might end and 0.3 seconds later the interval does it's check and plays the song, or a song might end right after the interval finished, so you'd have a gap of 2 seconds.

### Maintain a single `setTimeout`

It's similar to the first suggestion of clearing old intervals but not exactly the same.

The thing is that you don't *need* to keep checking if the song has finished playing, because you already know *when* it will finish. So, when it's played, you can use `setTimeout` to queue up the next song

```
//assuming wave returns time in milliseconds
var playNextIn = (wave.getDuration() - wave.getCurrentTime()) + 2000;

nextSongTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    /* code to play next song */
}, playNextIn);
```

So, this way you don't need to keep checking.

However, the only problem would be if a user clicks `pause` in which case you will need to call `clearInterval(nextSongTimer)` as it's no longer needed. So this way, you only need to kick off a timer once every time a song is played.

Comment: holy sh*t! what an answer :O thanks heaps for this! how would I integrate it though? very left in the dark as to where I would put this haha. I really love the idea of stopping the previous interval.

Comment: Well, if you want to stop the previous interval, your `playPause` function will need to set and unset the interval handle. However, the only thing here is that you need that to be defined _outside_ of the function, otherwise it will write the ID in the variable and when the function finishes, that variable will be discarded.

Comment: thankyou this works perfectly! :D will select as answer now. thankyou so much for taking the time to write this

Answer (score 1):

Every time you click the play/pause button, you call `setInterval`. So you're likely to have several time-based triggers at the same time and the condition probably keeps being true.

What if you replace your call to `setInterval` with:

```
var trigger = setInterval(function(){ // check every 2 seconds if the audio is finished playing
        if(wave.getCurrentTime() >= waveDuration){ // if it has make the play button, a pause button
            button.removeClass("playing");
            $(nextTrack + '-ppbutton').click(); // simulate new track play button click
            clearInterval(trigger);
        }    
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't really help me out.. Maybe a suggested alter? as I said, I'm not really that advanced with JavaScript